# PERL Get_Server_Certificate certificate verify failed error

Tags: perl, ssl, certificate, lwp

I'm receiving a certificate error when trying to send a POST message to a website.

The error I'm receiving:

`LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 49`

The code that I'm using is:

```
my $webpage = "";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( );
$ua->agent('Mozilla');

$webpage = "https://mysite:444/myapp/app.aspx";


my $msg = 'An XML Message';

my $req = POST $webpage, 
                 Content_Type => 'text/xml',
                 Content => $msg;
```

So far I've tried a few "fixes" that I've found online:

Tried disabling verify hostname through environment variable:
`$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;`

Tried disabling verify hostname through ssl_opts:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 }, );
```

Tried using the Mozilla CA and setting HTTPS_CA_FILE to `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem`?

At this point I'm out of options to try so I'm hoping someone has run into this problem before and can provide assistance.

Comment: Please indicate which versions of the libraries you are using, i.e. perl -MLWP::UserAgent -e 'warn LWP::UserAgent->VERSION'` and the same for LWP::Protocol::https and IO::Socket::SSL. Also check if the access is successful with a normal browser or if it complains too about invalid certificate.

Comment: Wow! I think you hit it on the nail! My LWP::UserAgent and IO::Socket::SSL are at the latest version, but the LWP::Protocol::https library wasn't even installed.  
In trying to install it though, I'm getting hung up at http-nb.t 1/14  
Have you encountered this before?

Comment: If LWP::UserAgent was installed as the newest version than you would not be able to do any HTTPS requests without having LWP::Protocol::https installed and thus you should not get this SSL related error message about certificate verification problems. And no, I did not get the errors in the test but please note that Perl 5.8.8. is a way old and totally unsupported version (and not even the last of the 5.8.x series) and there might be some problems nobody will fix.

Comment: Just saw that too, upgrading to perl 5.21.7 now. Hopefully this fixes my issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's just a typo, use "verify_hostname" without the "s":

> my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 }, );

Comment: Thanks for catching this, this was actually an error in my typing to StackOverflow and not in the original code.